# Feed email notification misfiring?

Tags: bug, notifications, rss

I just received an email notification of 6 items supposedly from the XSD feed, but they are not tagged as [xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xsd) or anything related.

This is new and unusual.  Bug?

[image]

---

**Update (2017-03-22)**

The misfiring occurred once again on the same day as my original report.  Sometime between then and now I began receiving email notifications regarding new XSD questions as expected.  I have not received any additional incorrect notifications after the initial two misfirings.

Comment: I notice they are all tagged with [tag:permissions].  Do you have email set up for that by chance?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Good observation, and potentially useful in diagnosing, but, no, I do not follow or have a feed setup for [permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/permissions).  I've since gotten another batch of notifications that also were all tagged with `permissions`.  I do not follow any of the tags for any of these questions.

Comment: Another report [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345371/new-questions-feed-using-the-wrong-tag) but that user got [tag:plotly] questions.

Comment: I just now got another email with the right questions.

Comment: I also repeatedly received mails with tags I did not subscribe to -- on of them obviously mistargeted [tag:raspberry-3] (instead of [tag:openpgp], the other one only had a single question (but did not contain [tag:xquery] as announced).

Comment: This has happened to me over the past couple of days as well.  I have an email feed setup for [meteor*] and continue to receive new question alerts for questions not containing any tags starting with "meteor"

Comment: Questions with unrelated tags were showing up the MATLAB chat room yesterday, but I didn't make note of any so I didn't comment at the time. Over the last 2 hours that I've been in chat, several new questions tagged [tag:matlab] have been asked but none have shown up on the feed. Seems like things are getting worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There definitely seems to be something amiss here; I'm the "tag person" (apparently we play a very literal game of [tag, you're it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_(game)) here) - investigating.

Edit: for context, we *have* recently deployed some changes to our tag related code (on a trial server that was serving 25% of requests) - but we have the ability to run tag queries against specific servers, and *it gets things right every time we try it*. So the issue *may or may not* be related to this trial server! While I investigate, I have disabled the trial server completely. This may or may not fix things - it'll be interesting to find out whether any new reports come in.

---

Update; using the well-known and practiced "hunch-based programming", I *suspect* I know what is happening, so:

- I've added some sanity checks to detect this scenario of very odd results coming back
- added extensive internal logging when a failure is detected
- made the code *discard* the results when a failure is detected, and repeat the operation using a different approach
- re-enabled the trial server (which is almost certainly at fault)

This should allow me to continue investigating the problem, while ensuring that users never see any side-effects from this (other than an extra few milliseconds, which they won't even know about in the case of emails).

---

Update: well [it happened again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292446/email-notification-for-incorrect-question), so I guess my hunch was wrong. Investigating more...

Comment: lol same edit same second.

Comment: Ummm... Interesting edit clash there...

Comment: Just a guess, of course: it could be the result of a race condition, perhaps resulting in a reference getting mis-directed. People notice that they get a wrong feed but they'd not notice that one has been omitted.

Comment: Hi Marc, no update since last week, I take it? Haven't received any more incorrect emails for [my issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292387/183627), but then it seems there haven't been any new entries in my filter since then either, so I can't confirm that it's back to working...

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter I'm still investigating; the suspect code has been deactivated for now

Comment: Appreciate the update, good luck with the bug hunt.

Comment: And just to confirm that the deactivation is working, I received an email for a correctly filtered question this morning (last night UTC).

Comment: @Amos since it is a rare event either way, that doesn't actually prove much; but: I'm glad it is ok