# New questions feed using the wrong tag

Tags: bug, tags, email, subscriptions

I am subscribed to the [sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sympy) tag. I get daily emails with new questions with that tag.

Today, I got this email:

[image]

As you can see, none of these are tagged sympy, although they are all tagged plotly (which I don't care about).

I'm assuming this is a bug. Here are the links to the questions:

[plotly - interactive outlier filter for scatter plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765349/plotly-interactive-outlier-filter-for-scatter-plots)

[plotly choropleth not plotting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764157/plotly-choropleth-not-plotting-data)

[R: ggplot and plotly axis margin won't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763280/r-ggplot-and-plotly-axis-margin-wont-change)

[Creating a Violin Plot and Scatter Plot with a Shared Y-Axis in Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751956/creating-a-violin-plot-and-scatter-plot-with-a-shared-y-axis-in-plotly)

[running plot in browser from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740103/running-plot-in-browser-from-python-script)