# Subscription Email based on tags suddenly stopped

Tags: support

I have various tags to which I have an email subscription to send me all the questions asked on specific topics on Stack Overflow. Suddenly this morning they stopped coming in. They are not in spam (before you ask). The Gmail account they go to is functioning fine (again before asked). I checked Stack Overflow, and I am still subscribed to all the tags.

Is there a problem with outgoing emails from Stack Overflow? Or is there something I need to do?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be related to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345357/feed-email-notification-misfiring

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the point in the right direction. Yes, it seems they may be related, but what I find strange is no one else seems to be complaining about it as far as I can tell. Well hopefully someone on the tech side will see this and have a solution. Thanks.